# Getting undefined from `this.refs[var-name].value`

Tags: react-native, pusher

I am using pusher for realtime updates. On client side there is multiple media is loaded from database. and adding `ref` to `<Text>` component and setting it's value to the current mediaID.

```
this.state.feed.map((media) => {
  <View>
    <Text ref={media._id}>{media.likes}</Text>
    <Text ref={media._id}>{media.name}</Text>
  </View>
})
```

I am accessing the value of `ref` in `componentDidMount` when binding the pusher trigger event.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  channel.bind('updateLikes', (data) => {
    alert(this.refs[data.mediaId].value)
  })
}
```

But, it's giving the `undefined` instead of the value of the `<Text>` component. I tried the solution from other posts, but i cound't find any of them working for my code.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? I think there is no value prop in react native Text

Comment: I want to update the value of <Text> component.

Comment: then you should update the state

Comment: How can i do that? because if i do setState inside of map(), state will be updated for every rendered media. and i want to change the number of likes of particular media by it's id.

Comment: you should change the feed array not the media item

Comment: what  inside  `data` you gotten from `updateLike`s event ?